# Numpy: an efficient way to implement sum of pairwise mins operation

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy

It's easy to do sum of products between two matrices, i.e.:

```
A = np.random.randn(100, 64)
B = np.random.randn(64, 100)
G = np.dot(A, B)
```

Is there a similar approach to do sum of pairwise mins between vectors ?

An inefficient approach is to do:

```
# For each row, col vector i,j in A and B respectively
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        G[i, j] = np.minimum(A[i], B[:,j]).sum()
```

So I am looking for something like:

`G = np.dot(A, B, operation=np.minimum)`

The goal is to avoid the slow for loops and to take advantage of numpy's BLAS implementation.

One major use case is the intersection of histograms kernel. An example is described in this great blog post:
http://blog.datadive.net/histogram-intersection-for-change-detection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straight-forward way would be to extend `A` to `3D` and leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.minimum(A[...,None], B).sum(1)
```

Comment: this is insanely good! the only issue is the memory requirement, but the speed is what I need right now :). I am curious to know if it's easy to do for sparse matrices but I'd leave that for another post! Thanks.

Comment: @Curious Yeah a sparse problem would require a different approach. So, might be a good idea to post a new one.