# Sparse Scipy/Numpy: an efficient way to implement sum of pairwise mins operation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Computing the sum of pairwise mins between vectors is very popular in natural language processing (NLP) and is used in computing the intersecting histogram kernel [1]. However, in NLP we frequently deal with sparse matrices.

Here is an inefficient way that uses the slow for loops to compute this operation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# Initialize sparse matrices
A = csr_matrix(np.clip(np.random.randn(100, 64) - 1, 0, np.inf))
B = csr_matrix(np.clip(np.random.randn(64, 100) - 1, 0, np.inf))

# For each row, col vector i,j in A and B respectively
G = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[1]):
        G[i, j] = A[i].minimum(B[:,j]).sum()
```

Is there a way to do this without the for loop ?
I wouldn't mind a for loop if it can be compiled such as with using `jit` in `numba`.

A fast dense version of this is given here: [Numpy: an efficient way to implement sum of pairwise mins operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309112/numpy-an-efficient-way-to-implement-sum-of-pairwise-mins-operation/47309169#47309169)

Thanks.

[1] http://blog.datadive.net/histogram-intersection-for-change-detection/

Comment: Are the nonzero values always positive?

Comment: So, they are not really sparse. Why are you using the sparse representation? Is it the memory efficiency that's bothering you?

Comment: @Divakar that's just for illustration, the matrices I am using are actually very sparse.

Comment: @hpaulj, the non-zero values are all positive!

Comment: So, you mean they are NumPy arrays but very "sparsey", as in many zeros?

Comment: Yes, has many zeros. Each row in the array has around 6 non-zero entries and the rest of the 100,000 entries in the row vector are zero.

Comment: I updated the arrays to make them sparse using paul's answer

Comment: But they are not really numpy arrays because I am using `csr_matrix` but I am assuming the `.data` or the non-zero entries of the sparse array are in numpy.

Comment: `sklearn` has a lot of pair-wise metrics, some of which work with sparse matrices.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics.  It has added some of its own compiled sparse utilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation that should be ok efficient, leveraging sparseness as best as it can. There is a loop but only along one dim, so should be not too bad.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, csc_matrix

M, N, K = 640, 100, 650

B1 = csr_matrix(np.clip(np.random.randn(N, K) - 1, 0, np.inf))
B2 = csr_matrix(np.clip(np.random.randn(N, K) - 1, 0, np.inf))
B = B1-B2
A1 = csc_matrix(np.clip(np.random.randn(M, N) - 1, 0, np.inf))
A2 = csc_matrix(np.clip(np.random.randn(M, N) - 1, 0, np.inf))
A = A1-A2

result = np.zeros((M, K))
for j in range(N):
    ia = A.indices[A.indptr[j] : A.indptr[j+1]]
    ib = B.indices[B.indptr[j] : B.indptr[j+1]]
    IA, IB = np.ix_(ia, ib)
    da = A.data[A.indptr[j] : A.indptr[j+1]]
    db = B.data[B.indptr[j] : B.indptr[j+1]]
    # both nonzero
    result[IA, IB] += np.minimum.outer(da, db)
    # one negative ...
    am = da<0
    iam, dam = ia[am], da[am]
    bm = db<0
    ibm, dbm = ib[bm], db[bm]
    # ... the other zero
    za = np.ones((M,), dtype=bool)
    za[ia] = False
    zb = np.ones((K,), dtype=bool)
    zb[ib] = False
    IA, IB = np.ix_(iam, zb)
    result[IA, IB] += dam[:, None]
    IA, IB = np.ix_(za, ibm)
    result[IA, IB] += dbm
# compare with dense method
print(np.allclose(result, np.minimum(A.A[..., None], B.A).sum(axis=1)))
```

Prints

```
True
```

Comment: looks great, going to try to see if it compiles with `numba`

Comment: @Curious glad to hear it. Btw. if your matrices have no negative entries then the code from `# one negative ...` down to the end of the loop is not needed. You can simply omit it. As  a matter of fact you should because that will make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least in recent versions of SciPy there is a function `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.minimum` [Link to documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.minimum.html) which is the equivalent of `numpy.minimum` in term of element-wise minimum. However, I don't know how computationally efficient that is.